# NavDeepLinkBuilder is not triggering onCreate on activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-deep-link

I am launching an DashboardActivity from notification what have deeplink built by:

```
NavDeepLinkBuilder(context)
            .setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph)
            .setDestination(...destination...)
            .setComponentName(DashboardActivity::class.java)
            .setArguments(...data...)
            .createPendingIntent()
```

However, DashboardActivity's `onCreate()` is not triggered. Why? Is this expected behavior?
I need `onCreate` triggered, because I have auth session check there.

Comment: Does the `DashboardActivity` associated with this paricular `R.navigation.nav_graph`?

Comment: @Zain yes it is

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link#handle